# Apply styling in tailwind.config.js based on light/dark mode

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS [typography](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin#adding-custom-color-themes) plugin in order to automatically style HTML elements. I'm customising the `code` block according the customisation guide on the wiki, which involves defining your own styling inside `tailwind.config.js`.

This is a sample that I'm using:

```css
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
      typography: {
        DEFAULT: {
          css: {
            'code': {
              'background-color': 'black',
            },
          },
        },
      },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ],
}
```

This works as expected: the `code` block is rendered with a black background. I would like, however, to render a black background when light mode is enabled and a white background when dark mode is enabled. I'm familiar with the `dark-` modifier which can be used throughout the HTML file, but I'm not sure how I can use the modifier inside `tailwind.config.js`.

I've tried adding a new modifier `dark` under `typography` (i.e. a sibling to DEFAULT with key "dark") with dark-specific stylings, but this did not change anything.

Note that I need to make this change in `tailwind.config.js`, the HTML is generated at runtime by a markdown generator so I cannot add css classes directly to the code block.